# Brownie framework FileNotFoundError: Cannot find tests/test_simple_storage.py

Tags: python, solidity, brownie

I am learning solidity according to reference(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M576WGiDBdQ&t=25510s)

When I tried to write run test under Brownie framwork,met an error that says can't find the file.

The ganache-cli works fine.
Using Macbook Pro ,intel not Apple M1 CPU.

Looking for help.Thanks.

This is the test script file in brownie tests folder.

```
from brownie import SimpleStorage, accounts

# Arrange
account = accounts[0]
print(account)
# Act
simple_storage = SimpleStorage.deploy({"from": account})
starting_value = simple_storage.retrieve()
expected = 0
# Assert
assert starting_value == expected
```

The error message.

```
(base) liwei@liweideMacBook-Pro Brownie_Simple_Storage % brownie run tests/test_simple_storage.py
Brownie v1.17.2 - Python development framework for Ethereum

BrownieSimpleStorageProject is the active project.
Attached to local RPC client listening at '127.0.0.1:8545'...
  File "brownie/_cli/__main__.py", line 64, in main
    importlib.import_module(f"brownie._cli.{cmd}").main()
  File "brownie/_cli/run.py", line 46, in main
    path, _ = _get_path(args["<filename>"])
  File "brownie/project/scripts.py", line 130, in _get_path
    raise FileNotFoundError(f"Cannot find {path_str}")
FileNotFoundError: Cannot find tests/test_simple_storage.py
(base) liwei@liweideMacBook-Pro Brownie_Simple_Storage %
```

This is deploy.py file in Brownie scripts folder

```
import os


def deploy_simple_storage():

    # load from you set encrypted , not from ganache-cli which is brownie automated connceted to
    # account = accounts.load("MG515-account")
    # print(account)

    # add private key use enviroment variables
    # account = accounts.add(os.getenv("PRIVATE_KEY"))
    # print(account)

    # .deploy() , always need a "from"key in a dictinary when making a transaction
    account = accounts.add(config["wallets"]["from_key"])
    simple_storage = SimpleStorage.deploy({"from": account})
    stored_value = simple_storage.retrieve()
    print("Current stored value is ：")
    print(stored_value)
    print("Updating Contract...")
    transaction = simple_storage.store(15, {"from": account})
    transaction.wait(1)
    updated_store_value = simple_storage.retrieve()
    print("Current stored value is ：")
    print(updated_store_value)


def main():
    deploy_simple_storage()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked your file path and file name?

`FileNotFoundError: Cannot find tests/test_simple_storage.py`

There should be `tests` folder and 'test_simple_storage.py` named test script file.

Comment: yes, I checked and copied the directory and pasted in terminal still error.

Comment: To run test, use `$ brownie test` or `$ brownie test tests/test_transfer.py`

Comment: Yes ,that what went wrong , I type brownie test tests/test_simple_storage.py,this tme ,the error info didn't pop up ,thank you .
I think I should read more about brownie docs.